# select helper selected value and nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form, like:

```
<% form_for @invoice do |f| %>
 <%= render :partial => "invoice_item_fields", :locals => {:f => f} %>
<% end %>
```

and _invoice_items_fields:

```
<% f.fields_for :invoice_items do |builder| %>
 <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", builder %>
 <%= builder.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :name) %>
 <%= builder.text_field :quantity, :size => 4,%>
<% end %>
```

When i submit the form and it not pass the validations it render the new action again. The thing is the selected value for :product_id is no remembered, but the :quantity is ok.
I read that i should setup an instance variable in the controller with the value of the selected option and then do something like:

```
<%= builder.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, :selected => @selected_product) %>
```

but the thing is the application could have many :invoice_items, so i don't know what to do for the select field "remember" the values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your controller code? I'd like to see where you're setting the invoice & invoice_item fields and how you're processing the form. I recently built an invoice & line_item application and might have some ideas... [Sorry I can't comment, but haven't hit that permission level.]

Comment: I solved this on another post. The thing was that my product_id was and string and not and integer at db level.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on another post. The thing was that my product_id was and string and not and integer at db level.